# Replace nested for loop with lambda function for pandas df

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, nested-loops

I have data at the user and page view level and am trying to develop a matrix that has the percent of the time two items have been viewed by the same user. Unsurprisingly, the nested for loop I've developed is extremely inefficient. I know a lambda function should be used here but am having trouble getting one that actually calculates what I need:

```
data = [['tom', '1'], ['nick', '1'], ['julie', '1'], ['tom', '2'], ['julie', '2'], ['tom', '3'], ['julie', '3']] 
visits_comb = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['USER_ID', 'PAGE_CLICKED']) 
visits_comb

page_id=pd.DataFrame(visits_comb.PAGE_CLICKED.unique(),columns=['PAGE_CLICKED'])
page_id

sim_mat=np.zeros(shape=(len(page_id),len(page_id)))

for index, row in page_id.iterrows():

    base_page=row['PAGE_CLICKED']

    for index2, row2 in page_id.iterrows():
        comparison_page=row2['PAGE_CLICKED']
        if base_page<comparison_page: 

            sessions=visits_comb[visits_comb['PAGE_CLICKED'].map(lambda x: x in [base_page,comparison_page])].groupby('USER_ID')['PAGE_CLICKED'].apply(lambda x: x.unique().shape[0])
            sim_mat[index][index2]=sessions.value_counts(2)[2]

print(sim_mat)
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data for all of this?  Otherwise you might not get the help you need.

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks for the suggestion! I've added sample data!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way that reduces time to run by about 60%. However, this is still a highly inefficient solution with a double for loop. Would love to get anyone's thoughts:

```
data = [['tom', '1'], ['nick', '1'], ['julie', '1'], ['tom', '2'], ['julie', '2'], ['tom', '3'], ['julie', '3']] 
visits_comb = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['USER_ID', 'PAGE_CLICKED']) 
visits_comb

page_id=pd.DataFrame(visits_comb.PAGE_CLICKED.unique(),columns=['PAGE_CLICKED'])
page_id

sim_mat=np.zeros(shape=(len(page_id),len(page_id)))

for index, row in page_id.iterrows():

    base_page=row['PAGE_CLICKED']

    for index2, row2 in page_id.iterrows():
        comparison_page=row2['PAGE_CLICKED']
        if base_page<comparison_page: 

            sessions=visits_comb['USER_ID'][visits_comb['PAGE_CLICKED'].map(lambda x: x in [base_page,comparison_page])].value_counts()
            sim_mat[index][index2]=sessions.value_counts(normalize=True)[2]

print(sim_mat)
```